# C recursion return values

Tags: c, function, recursion, return-value

I am trying to return a value from recursive function, but somehow keep getting the wrong value.

The function where im getting the wrong return value looks like this:

```
int statement_list(ParserData *data){

    int result = ERR_SYN;

    if(data->token.type == tt_right_bra)
    {
        if((result = load_token(data)) != 0) return result;

        return 0;
    }else if(data->token.type == tt_keyword_if    ||
            data->token.type == tt_eol            ||
            data->token.type == tt_id             ||
            data->token.type == tt_keyword_for    ||
           data->token.type == tt_keyword_return)
   {
       if((result = statement(data) != 0 )) return result;
       if((result = statement_list(data) != 0 )) return result; 

       return 0;
   }

   return result;
```

The program goes as expected, then enters function statement(), where it executes the following block:

```
else if (data->token.type == tt_left_par){
        if(check_if_id_declared(symtable, data->prev_token.attribute.value) != 1){
            result = ERR_SEM_BAD_DEFINITION;
            return result;
        }
}
```

Both if conditions are true (which is expected), variable result is set to 3 (macro is defined as 3) as it should be and the program returns to function statement_list with this value. In statement_list I now expect result = 3, however I keep gettin result = 1 after the program returns.

I have no idea why it does that, thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I would recommend re-writing the logic of the functions to create simplified and *minimal* example which demonstrates the problem. The cause of the bug will become obvious, or you will see that the simplified doesn't have the same problem, and that will give you a clue that one of the differences is causing the issue.

Comment: I see wrong paretheses. I guess `if((result = statement(data) != 0 )) return result;` must be `if ( ( result = statement(data) ) != 0 ) return result;`. `=` has lower priority than `!=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an operator precedence bug, because you were sloppy with your parentheses.

```
if((result = load_token(data)) != 0) return result;
```

is correct: the `(result = load_token(data))` expression is compared to zero.

```
if((result = statement(data) != 0 )) return result;
```

is wrong: the outer parentheses do nothing, and in `result = statement(data) != 0`, the `!=` operator has higher precedence than the assignment operator `=`. So this expression is evaluated as

```
result = (statement(data) != 0)
```

So, when `statement` returns 3, the expression `statement(data) != 0` is true, and `result` is set to the boolean `true` promoted to an integer, which is `1`.

Reference:

- [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)
- [implicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion)

  specifically **Integral promotion**, and even more specifically

  > the type `bool` can be converted to `int` with the value `false` becoming `​0​` and `true` becoming `1`

---

If you're actually writing C++ (as originally tagged), you can use strongly-typed enumerations for your return codes, and then you can't accidentally promote from bool like this.

If you're actually writing C (as currently tagged) - my links above are for the C++ docs, but C behaves the same way in this context. You don't have strongly-typed enumerations though, so you just need to be more careful.

Comment: Thank you so much, can't believe I overlooked that <3